# how to disable only end time of input range box highstock

Tags: highcharts

I want to display the chart with end time fixed. So one of the input range box "to" should be disabled. In this way, the user cannot change the end time of xAxis.
Or if not doing this way, maybe pass a date as start time of x-axis? 
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the simple way, you can overwrite drawInput function and remove focus event on max input.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q5p8j/5/

```
H.wrap(H.RangeSelector.prototype, 'drawInput', function (proceed, name) { ... });
```